# Change colour based on split function plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to use the "col" column to specify the colour needed for my plotly graph.

The code for the data frame and graph is as follows:

```
data <- data.frame(
  x= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
  y = c(10,11,10,12,11,9,8,13), 
  category = c("A","A","B","A","B","B","B","A"),
  col = c("#1e3d59","#1e3d59","#ff6e40","#1e3d59","#ff6e40","#ff6e40","#ff6e40","#1e3d59"))

plot <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, 
                     split = ~category, mode = 'lines', line = list(color = ~col)) %>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 20),
                 title = "X axis",
                 titlefont = list(size = 24),
                 dtick=1), 
    yaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 20),
                 title = "Y axis",
                 titlefont = list(size = 24)),
    margin = list(
      l = 50,
      r = 50,
      b = 100,
      t = 50,
      pad = 4),
    legend = list(font = list(size = 18))
  )


plot
```

But instead of the colours specified, I get the generic orange and blue colour of the graph below.
How do I rectify this? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to map the `col` column from `data`. Instead, you may provide `colors` per group in `plot_ly()` and then map `category` to `color`:

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, 
        type = "scatter" 
        mode = 'lines', 
        colors = c("#1e3d59", "#ff6e40"),
        color = ~ category)
```

[image]